# How to import a custom jar in node-red

Tags: java, node-red

I am trying to import a custom jar in the node-red java function (https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-java-function), but it is throwing an exception. I debugged and found that the code is added to a test class generated by node red. There are default imports in the class but I cannot find the template used for this pallete.

Any help/pointers are appreciated.

Comment: You are probably going to have to raise an issue directly with the node's creator. The github page is linked to from the flows link you provided. You will need to add a LOT more detail when you raise the issue, because what is in the question is not enough for anybody to help

Comment: Yes, realized the same. I ended up modifying the github branch. Will be uploading the new changes as contrib. Thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just FYI for anyone who comes on this path, the java-function node code was updated to let you include custom jars and import statements. This resolves the question